# How to display both data and image/pdf received from API in the Django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am receiving data and a file from REST APIs. I want to display data and the file in the same HTML template.

This file could be an image(jpg/jpeg) or a pdf file. I am able to display the data in the template. However I am not able to display the pdf/image file in the template.

Please help how system can detect the type of file (image or pdf) and then display the same in the template.
Below is my current code :

```
def get_invoice_details(request,myid=''):
    
    try:
       
       mark_url = urlDataApiEndpoint
       
       data = {
           "myId":myid
        }

       response = requests.post(url=mark_url, headers=header, json=data)
       inv_data = response.json()
      )

       mark_url1 = urlFileApiEndPoint
       
       data1 = {
           "myid":myid,
            
        }

      
       response1 = requests.request("POST", mark_url1, headers=header, json=data)
       inv_img = response1.content
       

       return render(request, 'myTemplate.html',{'inv_data':inv_data} , {'inv_img':inv_img})
    except KeyError:
        print(KeyError)
```

myTemplate.html

```
<div> {{inv_data.invno}}

</div>

<div>
 <iframe src="{{inv_img}}#view=fitH" title="PDF file" height="100%" width="200px" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content_type variable is then extracted from the response.headers dictionary. If the content type indicates that the file is an image, the image.html template is rendered with the file content as a context variable. If the content type indicates that the file is a PDF, the pdf.html

```
import base64

def file_view(request, file_url):
    response = requests.get(file_url)
    content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if 'image' in content_type:
        image_data = base64.b64encode(response.content).decode('utf-8')
        return render(request, 'image.html', {'image_data': f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{image_data}"})
    elif 'pdf' in content_type:
        pdf_data = base64.b64encode(response.content).decode('utf-8')
        return render(request, 'pdf.html', {'pdf_data': f"data:application/pdf;base64,{pdf_data}"})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Unsupported file type')
```

In your Django view, you can render this template with the image_data context variable set to the base64-encoded image data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Preview</h1>
    <img src="{{ image_data }}" alt="Image">
</body>
</html>
```

In your Django view, you can render this template with the pdf_data context variable set to the base64-encoded PDF data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PDF Preview</h1>
    <embed src="{{ pdf_data }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No Its not working. Its downloading the file on the frontend that too the frontend html code is getting downloaded not the file received from the API.

Comment: I am sending the file using res.download(path) from nodejs

Comment: If I use return HttpResponse(inv_img, content_type='application/pdf') then its directly showing the file in the brower window but not in the template. Which means the file is being received by django from the API correctly but I am not able to pass the pdf/image file to the template correctly.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot!